# removing some features from settings menu in android app

Tags: android, android-manifest, settings

I am developing an app with an open source code and I want to completely remove the feature of "Linked Devices" which is in settings.

I tried by deleting the string name from `strings.xml` file and by deleting the `android:label` from `androidmanifest` file. But it only removes the name and the feature is coming like this `@2343243545` and if we click on this option the app is getting stopped.

Suggest me something to remove this completely.

Here is the link to the open source code on which I am working `https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/tree/0a569676f7a57144374a24faef566b2ca3233290`

Comment: Please share your code...

Comment: https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/tree/0a569676f7a57144374a24faef566b2ca3233290

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to remove menu item, you can find menu XML files under `res/menu` directory inside project files.

Look for `<menu>` and delete `<item>` or `<group>` tag that you do not need.

Answer (score 0):

If the settings activity/fragment extends either the `PreferenceActivity`
or `PreferenceFragment` class, the drawing of the screen is driven by a file in the `res/xml` directory.  In this case, you will need to remove the Preference (Preference, CheckboxPreference, ListPreference, EditTextPreference, etc.) defined in a file that belongs to that path.  It is likely named preferences.xml.

If this is not the case/what you are looking for, please share the code that you are dealing with.

Comment: I deleted it from preference activity, still its coming the same. I cant provide you the whole project tell me the file you want to look into.

Comment: Can you show the settings activity source code and any relevant xml files?

Comment: this is the link of the open source project on which I am working https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/tree/0a569676f7a57144374a24faef566b2ca3233290